How to make title in header of memoir class in lowercase?
I have a tex file of memoir class:
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}
\setlrmarginsandblock{3.5cm}{2.5cm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{*}{1}
\checkandfixthelayout 

\begin{document}

\chapter{Well-posedness of MV-SDEs with
density-dependent drift}

\newpage

Something here.

\end{document}


Could you explain how to prevent the title

CHAPTER 1. WELL-POSEDNESS OF MV-SDES WITH DENSITY-DEPENDENT DRIFT

in the header row from being converted to uppercase? I would like

Chapter 1. Well-posedness of MV-SDEs with density-dependent drift

in slanted font. This would be less intrusive.

Here's an excerpt from p. 118 of the basic user manual of the memoir class:

Thus, the following may be what you're looking for.

\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}

\setlrmarginsandblock{3.5cm}{2.5cm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{*}{1}
\checkandfixthelayout 

\nouppercaseheads
\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Well-posedness of MV-SDEs with density-dependent drift}

\newpage
Something here.

\end{document}


Addendum to address @egreg's follow-up comment:

The default lettering style for text in the header row is slanted-roman. If you prefer to use true italic letters, I suggest you insert the following two instructions between \nouppercaseheads and \pagestyle{headings}:
\makeevenhead{headings}{\thepage}{}{\itshape\leftmark}
\makeoddhead{headings}{\itshape\rightmark}{}{\thepage}


And if you prefer simple upright letters, you should run
\makeevenhead{headings}{\thepage}{}{\leftmark}
\makeoddhead{headings}{\rightmark}{}{\thepage}



These pieces of information may also be gleaned from p. 118 of the memman document.
And, do please check out @egreg's parallel answer for further ideas on how to modify and improve the appearance of the header and footer lines.

Thank you very much for your help.

@Akira - You're most welcome.

It should also be possible to avoid the horrible slanted font…

@egreg - I've never liked the slanted-roman font either... I've posted an addendum to suggest how to switch to either true-italic lettering or to upright lettering.

In addition to \nouppercaseheads (which in my opinion should be default also for the standard classes, but they've been so for 40 years…), you might also want to avoid the slanted type, which might be replaced by italics with several font families, you can define your own style.
I suggest \small, so the reader will not be distracted. It's also necessary to change the odd foot for the chapter style, in this case.
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}

\setlrmarginsandblock{3.5cm}{2.5cm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{*}{1}
\checkandfixthelayout 

\nouppercaseheads
\makepagestyle{akira}
\makeevenhead{akira}{\small\thepage}{}{\small\leftmark}
\makeoddhead{akira}{\small\rightmark}{}{\small\thepage}
\makeoddfoot{plain}{}{\small\thepage}{}
\pagestyle{akira}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Well-posedness of MV-SDEs with
  density-dependent drift}

\section{Something here}

\newpage

Something here.

\newpage

Something here.

\end{document}


Add your own variations.

Could you elaborate on how to make the titles in heading italic? This would help differentiate it from the content in a page?

@Akira I wouldn't recommend it. Anyway \small\itshape would do (not for \thepage, please).

I think you are right. Keeping things simple and consistent are less distracting. I will keep it as in your original code.
